# Elementary Proof of Positive + Negative Decomposition of Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a compact, self-adjoint operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ I know that we can write it as $T=T_++T_-$ where $T_+$ and $T_-$ are, respectively, positive and negative and $T_+T_-=0$. However, all of the proofs that I can find of this fact seem to rely on using continuous functional calculus.

I was wondering whether it is possible to prove this result without resorting to results about $C^*$-algebras (which I don't really know much about).

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for compact operators?  That would certainly be enough here.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The existence of orthonormal eigenvector bases does make this question silly.

Answer (score 0):

As Omnomnomnom suggests, the "continuous functional calculus" is much easier in the case of compact selfadjoint operators. Indeed, $T$ is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix: 
$$\tag{1}
U^{-1}TU=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & & \\ & \lambda_2 & \\ && \ddots\end{bmatrix}, $$
where $U\colon \ell^2 \to \mathcal{H}$ is a unitary operator. Moreover, all eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ are real. The proof of this result is elementary.

To obtain the desired decomposition, just define 
$$T_+=U\begin{bmatrix} \max(0, \lambda_1) & & \\ & \max(0, \lambda_2) & \\ & & \ddots \end{bmatrix} U^{-1} $$
that is, eliminate all nonpositive eigenvalues. Change $\max$ with $\min$ to define $T_-$.